# Memory Leak in NSMutableDictionary initWithContentsOfFile

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutabledictionary

This is my code: (customNames and customNamesArray are static variables)

```
-(void) loadCustomDataFromDisk
{
  NSString *fullPath = [self filePathAndFileName: @"customData.plist"];

  if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: fullPath] )
  {
    NSLog(@"Loading file fails: File not exist");
    customNames = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    customNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  else 
  { 
    NSMutableDictionary *customItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fullPath];
    customNames = [customItems objectForKey: @"customNamesDict"];
    customNamesArray = [customItems objectForKey: @"customNamesArray"];

    if (!customItems)
      NSLog(@"Error loading file");

    [customItems release];
  } 
}

-(void) saveCustomDataToDisk
{
  NSString *path = [self filePathAndFileName: @"customData.plist"];

  NSMutableDictionary *customItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [customItems setObject: customNames forKey: @"customNamesDict"];
  [customItems setObject: customNamesArray forKey: @"customNamesArray"];

  BOOL success;
  success = [customItems writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
  if (!success)
    NSLog(@"Error writing file: customDataDict.plist");
  [customItems release];
}
```

According to Build and Analyze, I have a potential leak in loading customItems

```
NSMutableDictionary *customItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fullPath];
```

true enough, according to Instruments, I do have a leak in that part. But when I tried release or autoreleasing customItems, my app crashes. Even if I change NSMutableDictionary to NSDictionary, I still have the leak.
How do I fix this?

Any help would be very much appreciated. :) Thanks :)

Comment: its hard to see whats wrong in you code. can you show were do you release it? you obviously need to release it but it is hare to know why it is crashing without seeing more code.

Comment: Hi, I edited the original post to add more code :) Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retain customNames and customNamesArray because you are using reference from dictionary customItems and after passing reference you are releasing it.

customNames = [[customItems objectForKey: @"customNamesDict"] retain];

customNamesArray = [[customItems objectForKey: @"customNamesArray"] retain];

Now you can release customItems.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right as I can see. You can see answer here and may be it helps - [Leak problem with initWithContentsOfFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286565/leak-problem-with-initwithcontentsoffile)

I have only one question: You create NSString *fullPath and never release it. Is it autoreleased string? If so - your code is fine.